# Phone keeps downloading data with no user activity, where's the leak?

Tags: htc-droid-incredible, data-connection, data-monitoring

I've got a strange problem. My HTC Incredible running MIUI has a data leak of some sort.

It downloaded over 4 GB's of data last month and I can't seem to figure out where it's coming from.

I've installed Onavo and My Data Manager to track what's using the data and in Onavo i get 'Market Downloader' and in My Data Manager i get 'Download Manager'

I have barely installed any apps and certainly haven't downloaded 4GB of data, video streaming/downloading, or music. This never used to be the case and I've tried to delete as many of the apps as I could think of that might be doing this, but still nothing.

How can I pinpoint what's downloading this data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the three Incredibles we own had the same problem. It too was running MIUI.

I found [this thread on the MIUI forums](http://forums.miui.us/showthread.php?11988-Download-Manager-Data-Hog!-HELP!&p=61229&viewfull=1#post61229). After changing the build.prop file as indicated in that thread the problem went away.

Edit to add the following information:

> http://androidforums.com/incredible-all-things-root/447517-stop-update-notification.html
>
> Changed these lines to this:
>
> Do not try to parse ro.build.description or .fingerprint ro.build.description=3.26.605.1 CL264707 release-keys
>   ro.build.fingerprint=verizon_wwe/inc/inc/inc:2.3.4/GRJ22/222219:user/release-keys
>    end build properties
>
> It's really just the "build fingerprint" that matters as you can see.

If the MIUI is referencing an older version of Android then the carrier will keep trying to download the latest Android update. That's where the data download is coming from.

Comment: So, when the link no longer functions, what use is this answer?

Comment: Summarizing the link would be great :)

Answer (score 0):

Having two monitoring programs point to the same nondescript process is frustrating. Just to verify, does MIUI's built in Traffic Monitor ("Monitor" icon on your homescreen) show the same thing Onavo and My Data Manager?

In the likely event that it does, the most simple (and time consuming) answer is to systematically disable every single app until you identify the culprit. You would need to make sure to disable only one at a time then monitor traffic over a set period of time to look for a change. For most ROMs this means completely uninstalling apps to disable them, but MIUI's Monitor app also includes Firewall settings that allow you to disable data to specific apps on the fly (including system resources like Android System and Download Manager). I suggest working through the entire list even if you find a result earlier on.

You might also consider connecting to a WiFi router and monitoring your phone's traffic using the router's firmware or other network software. If you can identify where all this traffic is going it might give you a clue as to which app is requesting it all.

Answer (score 0):

This might be of some help. Because I had a similar problem on my 3G.
There must definitely be a feature called as "Background Data" somewhere in your Accounts and Sync Settings. Make sure it is disabled.

What this does is gives access to your apps to contact their servers and download data in the background, without your permission. This reduced my 3G usage considerably.

Second thing you might want to try is, Disable automatic update of all your apps in your phone. This is even worse and uses a lot of data.

Third and the most safest of all, turn your wifi or 3G OFF when you are not using it.

Comment: note that Background Data is only advisory, it is up to individual applications to whether or not to honour the setting.